# 10th Grade Algebraic Rate of Bacteria Growth Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

"A certain type of bacteria doubles every 6.5 hours. If there were 60 bacteria to start with, what is the hourly growth rate of the bacteria? How many bacteria will there be after a day and a half? Solve using algebra."

Another person was asking about this on here but I couldn't find the answer. I've come up with the equation $\ t = b2^{x/6.5}$ but I'm  not sure if this is right/where to go from here.

Comment: Your exponent is correct but $t$ is usually used as the time variable, not $x$. Your equation should be of the form $b(t)=b(0)\cdot2^{t/6.5}$ where $t$ is time in hours and $b(t)$ is the number of bacteria at time $t$.

Comment: Ah. Do I just begin to substitute in the provided numbers from there?

Comment: Yes, that would be the approach.

Comment: You can also use that $$N(t)=N_0e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: The hourly rate is $b(1)/b(0)$

Comment: what does $\ b(0)$ stand for in your equations? Specifically the $\ 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: In general the equation is $y=y_0\cdot a^t$, where $y$ is the poputlation of the bacteria after $t$ hours and $y_0=60$ is the initial population. Now you can deduce an equation from the following information:"A certain type of bacteria doubles every $6.5$ hours"

$$120=60\cdot a^{6.5}$$

Solve the equation for $a$ and obtain the function of the population.

Comment: why is it "$\ 120 =$"? where did you get that?

Comment: 120 is double of 60.

Comment: @andrewt Please give a reply if it is all clear now.

Comment: All clear. Thank you for the answer, sorry for the long response time.

Comment: No, problem. The reply wasn´t late at all. But a late reply is 100 times better than no reply.